# Run Lint/Sonarqube anaysis on generated code

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, static-analysis, javapoet

I'm working on an annotation processing library that generates java code using JavaPoet. It is composed by three modules

- An annotation processor
- A library that defines the annotations and some other helper code
- A test app that uses both

The whole thing is built using Gradle.
I have an environment with Sonarqube running and I can analyse the code with `./gradlew sonarqube`. However Sonar only scans under `src/main/java` for all three modules. I would like to be able to scan the `build/` directory of the `app` module to ensure that the generated code is fine, but I cannot find any clue on how to do this.
I would expect a way to instruct Sonar to scan other directories beside the default ones. Can anybody suggest an approach for this?

Comment: You can set the sonar.sources property. Take a look here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to make any difference. It's like that property is completely ignored.

Comment: Ok now it works, not sure why it wasn't before I probably did something wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed, for anyone interested just add a new source path to `sonar.sources`

```
property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java, app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/"
```